# How to refactor two complex classes with a lot of similar methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

Each of the classes contains about 30 methods and almost a half of them are same or very similar. And soon I am going to add a third class which is in the same situation with these two classes. I feel it is a mess to maintain or change them. How can I refactor to avoid the duplicate code?

Here is a simplified version:

```
public class A extends ContentPanel{
     private AMenuProvider menuProvider;
     private ADefinitionTree tree;

     public void sameMethod1(){
          ...
          menuProvider.do();
          tree.doSomething();
          ...
     }

     public void sameMethod2(){
          ...
          menuProvider.do();
          tree.doSomething();
          ...
     }

     public void differentMethodFromA(){
          ... // uses menuProvider and tree
     }


     ...
     // 10 similar methods and 20 different methods
} 

public class B extends ContentPanel{
     private BMenuProvider menuProvider;
     private BDefinitionTree tree;

     public void sameMethod1(){
          ...
          menuProvider.do();
          tree.doSomething();
          ...
     }

     public void sameMethod2(){
          ...
          menuProvider.do();
          tree.doSomething();
          ...
     }

     public void differentMethodFromB(){
          ... // uses menuProvider and tree
     }

     ...
     // 10 similar methods and 20 different methods

}
```

NOTE:  BMenuProvider vs AMenuProvider and ADefinitionTree vs BDefinitionTree could be very different implementation, but they provide a lot of same methods. Each of them has some unique methods which the other does not have.

I thought about creating an abstract class and extend it, but it seems ugly wherever I put the menuProvider and tree attributes. I am not sure whether there is any design patterns or solutions. Please help me refactor the classes so that I can remove the duplicate code.

Comment: if the functionality is the same why *wouldn't* a base class be a reasonable solution?

Comment: @DaveNewton Because the rest of 20 different methods like differentMethodFromA and differentMethodFromB also need to use the fields menuProvider and tree, I have to provide getter methods from the base class. Also I have to cast each time after I call a getter from the base class, which in my mind looks ugly.

Comment: Then there should be an interface that normalizes `MenuProvider` functionality.

Comment: @Alex why do you need to cast? You can use generics on the base class.

Comment: @JnRouvignac I mean from the subclasses, after I call the getMenuProvider() method, I have to cast it to AMenuProvider or BMenuProvider

Answer (score 0):

["S"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in [S.O.L.I.D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)):

> The single responsibility principle states that every module or class
>   should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality
>   provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely
>   encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned
>   with that responsibility.

["I"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle):

> The interface-segregation principle (ISP) states that no client should
>   be forced to depend on methods it does not use.[1] ISP splits
>   interfaces which are very large into smaller and more specific ones so
>   that clients will only have to know about the methods that are of
>   interest to them. Such shrunken interfaces are also called role
>   interfaces.[2] ISP is intended to keep a system decoupled and thus
>   easier to refactor, change, and redeploy.

["D"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle):

> A. High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both
>   should depend on abstractions. B. Abstractions should not depend on
>   details. Details should depend on abstractions.

You are violating (at least) these three sacred rules of OO. `A` and `B` should depend on **abstractions** (Interfaces). Same methods should be abstracted to one interface and different methods to different interfaces. S.O.L.I.D is more fundamental than design patterns. Design patterns are based on SOLID. Learn it first and you will have no more problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to reuse code (when code is duplicated across two or more classes).

- Inheritance: If all the participating classes (sharing duplicated code) are logically be put into a hierarchy where "is-a" relationship is followed than creating a base class, pull the common methods in the base class, and customize the subclass methods. (Consider using Template method pattern if there is a variation in method implementation across subclasses.)
- Composition: If the participating classes do not follow "is-a" relationship and hence cannot be placed in a hierarchy, create a class and put all the reusable methods in that. Use the class wherever you wanted to reuse the methods via composition.